# Management interface/SSH no longer working for HP MSA storage array

Tags: storage, hp, hp-modular-smart-array

I'm having issues accessing a storage array through the web interface/SSH on a MSA2324sa. I already emailed HP however I was wondering if anyone has ran into this. When I try to access the interface through the web browser that used to work (Mozilla Firefox 2), I now get a connection reset. Trying to access it through SSH would throw a `ssh_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host` error message. Running `dmesg` I see a lot of entries in the logs like the one below:

`mpt2sas0: log_info(0x31120432): originator(PL), code(0x12), sub_code(0x0432)`

I did find another post here - [Deciphering continuing mpt2sas syslog messages](https://serverfault.com/questions/407703/deciphering-continuing-mpt2sas-syslog-messages) - however, it's not *EXACTLY* clear what the issue might be. I did read the links supplied by Michael Hampton in that post and they seem to indicate that the array is under heavy load (which would make sense since it's a busy database server) however I just want to make sure there are no outstanding issues. The array was put in the datacenter in July and as of that time it had the latest firmware available. Any help would be appreciated on how to restore access to the array through SSH/web and decrypting the message log. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two issues.

Your [HP MSA2324](http://www8.hp.com/h20195/v2/getpdf.aspx/c04140210.pdf?ver=2) is a SAN connected via SAS. Your ability/inability to access the MSA2324's controller via its web or SSH interface are a separate issue from the messages presumably showing up *inside* of the OS of your Linux-based system. They may be linked, but there's clearly a problem with your storage.

So connect to your MSA using its serial interface. It's marked "CLI" on the rear. You likely have a bigger issue with the unit. If it's under support, call HP. If not, configure the serial using the manual's guide and get in to check the controller and array status.

If you have details about whether you are multipathed and/or have dual controllers properly configured, you could run a failover. But we don't have those details...

Comment: Unfortunately, we don't have dual controllers - only 1 controller. I'm also not multipathed, only one cable connecting the storage array. I'm waiting for a call from HP support to see what's up. The thing is there was a disk-scrub email being sent daily and that stopped in August and I believe this is when we lost access to the storage array's interface/SSH.

Comment: Please reboot it. ;)

Comment: Unfortunately that's not something I can do on the fly since it hosts a huge database that has to be live. HP suggested as well that we connect to it using the serial interface.